# Pandas concat producing NaN

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have a series of CSVs that I'm importing using `read_csv`

Each csv has a structure like:

```
lig1,-6.3
lig2,-6.5
```

By reading in all the files, and associating each import to a key, I've been trying:

```
df = []
for conf in FOLDER:
    df.append(pd.read_csv(conf+'/summary.csv', names=['ligand', self.__getDirNameFromPath(conf)]))

print pd.concat(df)
```

I get this:
[image]

I would like to basically remove the NaNs, there should be two rows in this case (excluding headers). Also, having the ligand column as the index would be good too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `concat(df, axis=1)`.

Comment: Arg, swear I tried that and it was erroring out, thanks. 

Also for anyone looking at this, I got the ligand column as an index by passing `index_col=0`.